# WCF RIA services and WSDL generation

Tags: wcf, wsdl, wcf-ria-services, ria, nested-class

Need help on an issue I am having. I inherited this WCF RIA project and am trying to understand a couple of things.

When I publish the project, how does the WSDL get generated and put on the URL that I published to?

And I want to incorporate FaultException handling so as to transmit the exceptions to the client side. I read some stuff regarding the FaultException on the web and was able to get a small sample working with the regular WCF service.

I thought it would be similar within my actual project. But unfortunately I am running into some issues(probably due to my lack of WCF + RIA services knowledge).

So in my actual project my Context class derives off of LinqToEntitiesDomainService.

I created a new ContextFaultException class which had some methods to capture some custom error messaging. 
Then I applied the [FaultContract(typeof(ContextFaultException))] to some of the methods in my Context class. Everything compiles and all is fine. But when I published to a website and then when I added this service reference to the client, I don't see my new ContextFaultException in the Reference.cs file that's generated. 
I thought may be moving it within the Context class will solve the issue. So I made my ContextFaultException class as an inner class of this Context class but I am running into some other issues. Before I try to figure out these issues, I just want to know if this the right approach?

Any suggestions/pointers??

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The URL must be formatted to get to the namespace wdsl

for example:

```
namespace My.Namespace.Services
{
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public partial class MyClassName : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<XXX>
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Then use the following pattern for the url

```
http://YOURHOST/APP/Services/My-Namespace-Services-MyClassName.svc?wsdl
```

Use "-" for the "."